Galois Representation
I was having a conversation with a professor about Modular forms and Galois representation, and at some point, she said ''If we think on the Galois side, then the representation has irreducible inertia''.
I know the definition of decomposition group and inertia subgroup. But I did not get the above statement.
Can someone give some idea about it?
Is there any relation with the coefficient $a_2(f)$ of a modular form $f$ and the local representation attached to it which relates to the above statement (somehow)?

I think this is an excellent question to ask your professor again. I am sure she won't mind coming back to it.

@NonAffine Thanks for your suggestion. I do not want to bother the professor for small doubts. Since I know that by inertia, we mean a group/subgroup, I certainly do not understand the "irreducible inertia". I could not find it in any article and hence I am asking here.

As someone who teaches, I always love it if students come back to me to ask a follow-up question or clarificiation. It shows interest in the material and a desire to understand. If she is too busy or does not have time to answer your question, she will tell you. As for your question here, I do not think it is quite precise enough to be able to answer it, which is why I suggested you talk to your professor as she is likely to have more context in mind than what you described here.

Here, “irreducible inertia” certainly means that the restriction to the inertia subgroup of the representation is irreducible. There are likely “equivalents” on the modular side, but the claim needs to be made more precise (which representation? Which inertia subgroup?).
